# When my android application is loaded on my phone, the format of buttons' layout it weird. However, it is fine on the emulator

Tags: java, android

Basically title. When I run my app (a simple 3x3 grid-type game) it works properly and pulls up a 3x3 grid as it should on the Nexus phone emulator. However, whenever I run the application on my phone, the grid is 2x3. I am thoroughly confused and any help would be great :)

Comment: You can fix the number of column from xml

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because the screen size or pixel density is different of your emulator and android phone

Answer (score 0):

android phone has different density 
your phone has lower screen density (lower resolution) than emulator, and it can't show all of the content !

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop your app to support various screen sizes and densities, this link will help :- http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Use 9 patch for images,buttons , etc to maintain proper aspect ratio for various screen sizes.